# how to count line in text file and insert it in the first line

Tags: 16.04

I have more than 1000 text file, I want to count line number in each file and insert it in the first line.
I count it with wc but i can't insert it .

```
wc -l *.txt |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
for f in *.txt; do sed -i "1i$(wc -l < "$f")" "$f"; done
```

`1i` inserts text before the first line, and `-i` causes the change to be written to the file in place.

---

A purist would probably use `ed` in place of `sed`:

```
for f in *.txt; do printf '0r !wc -l < %%\n,wq\n' | ed -s "$f"; done
```

Comment: yeah its work just like i want it :D thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (easily) *prepend* something to a file. 
So a temporary file is needed, like so:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)       # temp. file
    wc -l "$f" > $tmpfile   # store number of lines 
    cat "$f" >> $tmpfile    # append file content
    mv "$tmpfile" "$f";     # move temp. file to original file
done
```

Comment: thank you it works but it add the file name in front of line number can't we delete the file name ?

Comment: Use `wc -l < "$f" > $tmpfile` then, so `wc` reads stdin and not the file.